# Residence in the UK under new EEA regulations

Tags: united-kingdom

I'm a European who holds EU and UK passports, permanently living in the UK. I registered my marriage with a non-EU citizen in the UK a year ago. She lives in the UK as the spouse of a British citizen, holding a FLR(M) for 5 years (subject to prolonging).

Is it possible to replace her visa to residence as an EU family member according to changes in EEA regulations from 24/07/2018?

Can you please share a link to the proper application form on the gov.uk site?

Thank you!

Comment: The change affects dual citizens differently depending on the circumstances of their dual citizenship, so the question does not contain enough information.